# pass parameter to onmouseover event

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I'm trying to pass a parameter to an onmouseover event like this:

```
    function obj(id){
        if (!(this instanceof obj)) return new obj(id);
        this.element = (typeof id === 'string') ? document.getElementById(id) : id;
    }
    obj.prototype.call = function(content){
        this.element.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
            console.log(content); // => undefined
            // My mistake is right here.
            var content = 'Hello';
        },false);
    };
//Edit
    function temp(){}
    temp.prototype.content = function(){
        return 'Hello World';
    };
    var temp = new temp();
    obj('id').call(temp.content());
```

I can't figure out why variable `content` is `undefined`. And also, how could I make it right?

Somebody please helps me out of this. I really appreciate that.

Comment: *I can't figure out why variable content is undefined* - [it's not](http://jsfiddle.net/97tcW/).

Comment: I've just editted my question. Actually I call `Hello World` from another scope.

Comment: The edited code works perfectly fine as well

Comment: Second that. To the OP: couldn't you just check the examples you're trying to come with in jsfiddle _before_ posting them?

Comment: I will never understand why people include code that's not the actual code that's giving them problems.

Comment: Just because I have no idea about my problem. And I also try to shorten my messy code. ~~

Comment: That's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EfL5V/) for the `<div>` change; it works as well. And that's the last time I've been doing _your_ work.

Comment: See this [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page. Pay specific attention to the last part (Verifiable).

Comment: Thank you all guys. I found my problem. My mistake is right on redefining variable `content`. Sorry about your time. ~~

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your callback is executed with different scope or something like this.

Try to use closure:

```
obj.prototype.call = function(content){
    this.element.addEventListener('mouseover',(function(content){
        return function(){
            console.log(content); // => undefined
        };
    })(content),false);
};
```

Comment: It's useless to wrap `content` this way. Each time `call` function is invoked, a new function is created - and its context binds the existing `content` variable. The relation between `mouseover` handler and the name stored in it is 1-1.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ANB3z/

Either your id is not valid (in which case you'd be getting a different error), or the 'undefined' message you are seeing is a result of running the script itself in the console, rather than the `mouseover` event.

Comment: It can a typo also: compare `content` with `сontent`.